# Search through the whole session in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I have many chapters in my work and each chapter has a separate tex file. Now when I want to change something, I switch to each tex file and repeat Ctrl+R in each tex file. This is a little bit annoying and penalizing modularity. Is there a better way? Sort of, a "master search" in TeXstudio?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open your search using [Ctrl+F] or [Ctrl+R] and then click on the Plus (+) button on the right of the search field opening the advanced search. See the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here, I have only the main document opened and it can find strings in all files and replacing works, too.

Comment: That's better. I only had version 2.6.6, as that is the newest in the (K)ubuntu repos. I don't ever use TS, so I haven't concerned myself with getting the latest and greatest.

Comment: TeXstudio has been improving a lot over the last years and months in many small steps. A huge thing is the automatic recognition of projects and master files (semi-automatic works even if the master file isn't open).